# PointSymbolA=none?

Tags: pstricks

I tried to compile a older .tex-file. But I received an error for the option PointSymbolA=none in the pstInterLC-command: Dot style 'none' not defined. I used this option in several documents, but now it doesn't work anymore.
Can you help?

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{article}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
 \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,5)
  \pstGeonode[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none](0,0){O}(4,3){A}(0,3){B}
  \pstInterLC[PointName=none,PointSymbolA=none]{O}{A}{O}{B}{C}{D}
 \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Use `\PointSymbol={none,*,none}` instead of setting `\PointSymbolA` or use the version 1.58 from 
http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/texnik/tex/generic/pst-eucl/
Then you can use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,5)
    \pstGeonode[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none](0,0){O}(4,3){A}(0,3){B}
    \pstCircleOA{O}{B}\pstLineAB[linecolor=red]{O}{A}
    \pstInterLC[PointName=none,PointSymbolA=none]{O}{A}{O}{B}{C}{D}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this problem has been asked before : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/fr.comp.text.tex/QY1TjKr-hX8/XrTWKrE_nKgJ.

Comment: yes, but that is an undocumented feature

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response. \PointSymbol={none,*,none} gave the same error, but the older package did the work. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE. You need to define the points/nodes A,...,D before you use them. And you are right, it seems not to be possible to assign `none` to `PointSymbolA`. You could, however, assign `none` to all symbols and then set the symbols for `B` and `C` differently. And then there is, as far as I know, no option `pstricks` that can be passed to the `article` class.

```
\documentclass{article} % <- removed [pstricks]
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
 \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,5)
 \pnodes(0,0){A}(0,3){B}(6,3){C}(6,0){D}(0,0){O}
 \pspolygon(A)(B)(C)(D)
  \pstGeonode[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none](0,0){O}(4,3){A}(0,3){B}
  \pstInterLC[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none,
  PointSymbolB=o,PointSymbolC=o]{O}{A}{O}{B}{C}{D}
 \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```